# configure maven to download a dependency parallely

Tags: maven, build, maven-3, maven-plugin

I have a scenario like this:

> module 1:
>
> > module 2:
> >
> > module 3:
> >
> > module n: large file dependency

Now maven builds the projects one by one. I have a dependency in module n which takes a lot of time to download.

How to configure maven so that although the sequence of build happen in the same way that particular dependency starts to download initially. So, that when it reaches module n for install the dependency is already downloaded (or partly downloaded)

Answer (score 0):

You can use few things:

#### use parallel building in maven

```
mvn clean install -T4
```

#### start another process (e.g. in background) that will do the download

```
mvn dependency:resolve
```

Comment: Actually the dependencies are not proper and a lot of scripts run. In short when I run with multiple threads (-T4) it fails. I will try the other option mentioned but I want to explicitly download a few dependencies parallely..that's all

Comment: Other than that it is not possible with maven alone.  You need to hack around it e.g. with dependency:resolve